# R Network Analysis: Color of edges and vertices

Tags: r, graph, igraph, network-analysis

I have created a graph with the igraph-Package in R. [image: created Graph]

Now i want to make the graph more colorful. I want to color my network based on the type of "party" in my dataset. My dataset looks like this:

```
    Screen.name     mentions           party
  1 @A_Gloeckner    @MartinSchulz      SPD
  2 @A_Gloeckner    @MartinSchulz      SPD
  3 @A_Gloeckner    @MartinSchulz      SPD
  4 @A_Gloeckner    @ManuelaSchwesig   SPD
  5 @A_Gloeckner    @sigmargabriel     SPD
  6 @A_Gloeckner    @nahlesMeine       SPD
  ... ...           ...                ...
 33 @A_Schillhaneck @BA_Mitte_Berlin   GRNE
 34 @A_Schillhaneck @nytimes           GRNE
 35 @A_Schillhaneck @nutellaberliner   GRNE
```

This is the code how i have created my graph:

```
gj <- graph.data.frame(joined_df, directed = TRUE)
plot(gj,
 vertex.label = NA,
 vertex.size = 2,
 edge.arrow.size = 0.1,
 vertex.label.cex = 0.8,
 layout = layout.fruchterman.reingold)
```

The graph:

```
> gj
IGRAPH c5ba2ee DN-- 1279 2147 -- 
+ attr: name (v/c), color (v/c), party (e/c)
+ edges from c5ba2ee (vertex names):
[1] @A_Gloeckner->@MartinSchulz    @A_Gloeckner->@MartinSchulz    
@A_Gloeckner->@MartinSchulz   
[4] @A_Gloeckner->@ManuelaSchwesig @A_Gloeckner->@sigmargabriel   
@A_Gloeckner->@nahlesMeine    
[7] @A_Gloeckner->@Willy           @a_grotheer ->@NSC_CPMR        @a_grotheer 
 ->@SouthendRNLI   
[10] @a_grotheer ->@weserkurier     @a_grotheer ->@werderbremen    
@a_grotheer ->@ribasdiego10        
+ ... omitted several edges
```

Now i want the edges and vertices to be an own color for every different "party". In this case i just got two different parties ("SPD", "GRNE").
I want every node and vertice with the "party"-Value "SPD" to be red, and every value with "GRNE" to be green.

Does anybody know how to do this?

I know that i can change the colors with for example `vertex.color = "red"` or `edge.color = "red"`, but i don't know how to set the color on dependencies.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `set_edge_attr` like below

```
graph.data.frame(joined_df, directed = TRUE) %>%
  set_edge_attr(name = "color", value = c("red", "green")[match(joined_df$party, c("SPD", "GRNE"))]) %>%
  plot(
    vertex.label = NA,
    vertex.size = 2,
    edge.arrow.size = 0.1,
    vertex.label.cex = 0.8,
    layout = layout.fruchterman.reingold
  )
```

[image]

---

If you have more colors and want to color edges automatically, you can try

```
graph.data.frame(joined_df, directed = TRUE) %>%
  set_edge_attr(name = "color", value = factor(joined_df$party)) %>%
  plot(
    vertex.label = NA,
    vertex.size = 2,
    edge.arrow.size = 0.1,
    vertex.label.cex = 0.8,
    layout = layout.fruchterman.reingold
  )
```

where the `factor` should be used over `party` for the values of color.

[image]

## dummy data

```
> dput(joined_df)
structure(list(Screen.name = c("@A_Gloeckner", "@A_Gloeckner",
"@A_Gloeckner", "@A_Gloeckner", "@A_Gloeckner", "@A_Gloeckner",
"@A_Schillhaneck", "@A_Schillhaneck", "@A_Schillhaneck"), mentions = c("@MartinSchulz",
"@MartinSchulz", "@MartinSchulz", "@ManuelaSchwesig", "@sigmargabriel",
"@nahlesMeine", "@BA_Mitte_Berlin", "@nytimes", "@nutellaberliner"
), party = c("SPD", "SPD", "SPD", "SPD", "SPD", "SPD", "GR<dc>NE",
"GR<dc>NE", "GR<dc>NE")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1",
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "33", "34", "35"))
```